# Best way to get value of Form Control ComboBox

Tags: excel, vba

I have been using a bunch of Form Control ComboBoxes and in my code I need the ComboBox's currently selected value. I have been calling the List and then the box's ListIndex to achieve this:

```
ws.Shapes("ComboBox1").ControlFormat.List(ws.Shapes("ComboBox1").ControlFormat.ListIndex))
```

So I'm wondering, surely there's a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: Are you sure that you are talking about `Form` type sheet combo boxes? Their suggested name is something as "Drop Down1". Did you change it in "Combobox1"?

Comment: Yes, form controls I just chose a random name without thinking sorry! @FaneDuru

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you did not answer my clarification question, please use the next function, able to return the combo value, independent of its type:

```
Function GetComboBoxValue(strName As String)
   Dim sh As Worksheet, s As Shape
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here the sheet you need...
  For Each s In sh.Shapes
     If s.name = strName Then
        If TypeName(s.OLEFormat.Object) = "DropDown" Then      'Form combo box
           GetComboBoxValue = s.OLEFormat.Object.List(s.OLEFormat.Object.Value): Exit Function
        ElseIf TypeName(s.OLEFormat.Object) = "OLEObject" Then 'ActiveX combo box
           GetComboBoxValue = s.OLEFormat.Object.Object.Value: Exit Function
        End If
     End If
  Next
End Function
```

Or without iteration between shapes:

```
Function comboValue(strName As String)
   Dim sh As Worksheet, s As Shape
   
   Set sh = ActiveSheet
   Set s = sh.Shapes(strName)
    If TypeName(s.OLEFormat.Object) = "DropDown" Then      'Form combo box
        comboValue = s.OLEFormat.Object.List(s.OLEFormat.Object.Value): Exit Function
    ElseIf TypeName(s.OLEFormat.Object) = "OLEObject" Then 'ActiveX combo box
        comboValue = s.OLEFormat.Object.Object.Value: Exit Function
    End If
End Function
```

They can be tested in the next way:

```
Sub testGetComboVal()
   Debug.Print GetComboBoxValue("ComboBox1")
   Debug.Print comboValue("ComboBox1")
End Sub
```

Please, send some feedback after testing it.

Comment: Yep, this works great! Don't know why I didn't think of just making a function before...

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can get it with `OLEFormat.Object`

```vb
Sub demo()
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    'Debug.Print ws.Shapes("ComboBox1").ControlFormat.List(ws.Shapes("ComboBox1").ControlFormat.ListIndex)
    With ws.Shapes("ComboBox1").OLEFormat.Object
        ' Get the value of ComboBox
        Debug.Print .List(.Value)
        ' Below code is for demo, it is not related with get the value
        Debug.Print .Name
        .Select
    End With
End Sub
```

Please ref to Micrsoft document.

> [OLEFormat.Object property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.oleformat.object?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

Comment: Unfortunately, this just gives me the index of the selected item, similar to .ControlFormat.ListIndex does, maybe a different property would work?

Comment: You can get the selected value with `.List(.Value)`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
With ws.Shapes("ComboBox1").ControlFormat
    Debug.Print .List(.ListIndex)
End With
```

... with `Debug.Print` replaced with whatever you want to do with the text of the selected item. Whether this is 'cleaner' I'll let you decide!! But there is no way to access the text of the selected item (that I know of) without accessing both the `List` and the `ListIndex`